# dictionary Value of type 'Int?' has no member

Tags: ios, swift

I use this code that find value for key in dictionary and remove value.

```
var downloadQ = [Int: Int]()

downloadQ[id] = indexPath.row
```

but I get error in this line `if let idx = downloadQ[id].index(of: indexPath.row) {` error: `Value of type 'Int?' has no member 'index'`

```
if let idx = downloadQ[id].index(of: indexPath.row) {
    self.downloadQ[id].remove(at: idx)
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? The values in your dictionary are `Int`s, not arrays.

Comment: I dont know swift, but `downloadQ[id]` should return an int right? so that doesn't have an index

Comment: `downloadQ.removeValue(forKey: id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the value under the given key, use this:

```
if downloadQ[id] == indexPath.row {
    downloadQ.removeValue(forKey: id)
}
```

Read its [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/1641348-removevalue).

Or alternatively, you can use:

```
if downloadQ[id] == indexPath.row {
    downloadQ[id] = nil
}
```

If you would use dictionary with `[Int]` as values (`var downloadQ = [Int: [Int]]()`, then you would use the code that you had originally in the question (just with `?` to unwrap optional):

```
if let idx = downloadQ[id]?.index(of: indexPath.row) {
    self.downloadQ[id]?.remove(at: idx)
}
```

Comment: Please **not** `...value(forKey`. Do you think that KVC is really necessary?

Comment: @vadian this has nothing to do with KVC, its this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/1641348-removevalue

Comment: You mean `downloadQ[indexPath.row] = nil`? Note that `indexPath.row` is not the index but the value.

Comment: @Sulthan I guess `downloadQ[indexPath.row] = nil` is an alternative, you are right with the `indexPath.row`, I fixed that

Comment: I apologize. I suffer from a *KVC-misuse-trauma* 

Comment: @MilanNosáľ At first I want to check if value for key `id` in my dictionary equal `indexPath.row` and after remove this value from dictionary.

Comment: @MilanNosáľ also I use this code for my array: `downloadQ.contains(indexPath.row)` Is there a similar code for my dictionary?

Comment: @111 do you use `indexPath.row` as key or value in the dictionary? depends on that..

Comment: @MilanNosáľ as value

Comment: @111 then this would be the equivalent to it: `downloadQ.values.contains(indexPath.row)`

Comment: @MilanNosáľ and if I change this `var downloadQ = [Int: Int]()` to this `var downloadQ = [Int: [Int]]()` after I append `indexPath.row` in dictionary: `downloadQ[id]!.append(indexPath.row)`. And how I can find value in array for key in dictionary and remove value?

Comment: @111 if you want to remove it from the array that you get by `downloadQ[id]`, you can use the same code as you had - see the update in the question

Comment: @MilanNosáľ and this line :`downloadQ.contains(indexPath.row)` should be like this: `(downloadQ[id]?.contains(indexPath.row))!` ? But my app crashes on line with this error `EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1008b15dc)` Why?

Answer (score 1):

Only guessing what you are trying to do. If you want to remove the index from the `downloadQ` only if the value is the same as `indexPath.row`:

```
if downloadQ[id] == indexPath.row {
  downloadQ[id] = nil
}
```